# Ember.js: working next and previous buttons do not work on browser reload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am new to Ember.js but quite satisfied with my progress. I managed to get some [older code](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/linking-to-the-next-previous-item-in-list-of-items/773/18) working with the latest version, but when it comes to debugging i am an complete noob.

So I added these buttons to browse through an array of models. Everything works fine, but when I refresh my browser at `localhost:4200/services/1` it stops working.

Here is my controller:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['services'],
  actions: {
    prevItem: function() {
      return this.advanceItem(-1);
    },
    nextItem: function() {
      return this.advanceItem(1);
    }
  },
  advanceItem: function(delta) {
    var index, length, items;
    items = this.get('controllers.services');
    length = items.get('length');
    index = (items.indexOf(this.get('content')) + delta + length) % length;
    console.log(items.indexOf(this.get('content')) + ' ' + delta + ' ' + length);
    return this.transitionToRoute('service', items.objectAt(index));
  }
});
```

The ServiceController does not receive anything from 'controllers.services' and I don't know why? Any help?

The complete project is available on [Github](https://github.com/PDXIII/Ember-Single-Page). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you jump in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63494/ember-js) ?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. You might have recognized, I wasn't able to join the chat.

Comment: Now I am in the chat!